# Find $P + Q + R$

Tags: arithmetic

I was doing questions from previous year's exam paper and I'm stuck on this question.

> Suppose $P, Q, R$ are positive integers such that $$PQR + PQ + QR + RP + P + Q + R = 1000$$ Find $P + Q + R$.

It seems easy but I am not getting the point from where I should start. Thank you.

Comment: Expand $(1+p)(1+q)(1+r)$ , not sure if it may help.

Comment: It will help. But one should factorize 1001, and appeal to Unique Factorization Theorem

Comment: @Mann thank you for your comment.
Your equation comes out to be the same as the question but what next!.
I am not getting how to proceed further

Comment: @PVanchinathan 
Please explain.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note that

$(1 + P) (1 + Q) (1 + R) = 1 + P + Q + R$
$+ PQ+ PR + QR + PQR = 1 + 1000 = 1001, \tag{1}$

by the hypothesis on $P$, $Q$, $R$;  also,

$1001 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13, \tag{2}$

all primes; thus we may take

$P = 6; \;\; R = 10; \;\; Q = 12, \tag{3}$

or some permutation thereof; in any event, we have

$P + Q + R = 28. \tag{4}$

***Note Added in Edit, Saturday 12 August 2017 10:04 PM PST:***  The solution is unique up to a permutation of $(P, Q, R) = (6, 10 ,12)$ by virtue of the fact that $1001$ may be factored into three non-unit positive integers in exactly *one* way, $1001 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$, since $7$, $11$, and $13$ are all primes.  This follows from the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).  These remarks added at the suggestion of user21820 made 5 May 2015.  Sorry about the delayed response.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Beat me to it. Once you spot the factorization, the rest is trivial.

Comment: @amighty:  you're more than welcome!  Blessings to you as well!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!  ;-)!

Comment: Do add the justification why there are no other solutions.

Comment: How should one go about solving this if you don't spot the factorization?

Comment: @GarethRees: It is possible to spot the factorization without prior knowledge - in my case, it began when I factored the first two terms into PQ(R+1), and I remarked that I could make the term (R+1) emerge elsewhere.

Comment: @Gareth Rees the symmetry of the expressions $P+Q+R$, $PQ+QR+RP$, $PQR$ should suggest this has something to do with the roots of a cubic polynomial. Or you could try letting $S = P+Q+R$, expanding $S^2$ and $S^3$, and constructing a cubic equation for $S$.

Comment: @JeanHominal: I'm not asking, "how do I factorize a polynomial?" I'm asking, "what feature of the problem indicates that factorization is a good first step?" which alephzero has answered.

Comment: @user21820:  I will add a few remarks along those lines after I get a little more sleep!  Cheers!

Comment: @smci:  yes, factoring $P + Q + R + PQ+ PR + QR + PQR$ is the key.  Think elementary symmetric functions.  That's what I did!  Cheers!

Comment: It's funny that factorisation of LHS (seen some question before) just came into my brain just 10 sec after seeing the statement. I probably knew it but didn't try factorising the RHS. haha

Comment: @user21820:   I finally honored my word to add what you requested.  See above.  Sorry it took so long.  Cheers!

Comment: Not a problem at all. I completely forgot about it myself! Have a nice day! =)

Answer (score 2):

If you allow some $p,q,r$ to be $0$, you also get $$p+q+r=1000$$ $$p+q+r=88$$ $$p+q+r=100$$ $$p+q+r=148$$

for $$p=1000,q=0,r=0$$ $$p=76,q=12,r=0$$ $$p=90,q=10,r=0$$ $$p=142,q=6,r=0$$

respectively, or any permutation thereof.

Comment: Note that the question asked for *positive* $P, Q, R$.

Comment: Yep. Always fun to extend though!

Comment: Indeed! Excelsior! Cheers!

Comment: Here at Terrapin Crossroads, Phil Lesh's bar in San Rafael, CA, I think your idea just hit me:  e.g. let $R = 0$ and look at $P + Q + PQ$ etc., right?

Comment: Yup, you can use the same method as before. The terms $(1+p),(1+q),(1+r)$ must be divisors of $1001$, so then we just go through them all. Location noted!

Comment: You been here?  Anyway, now that I get your idea, ***endorsed!!!***

Comment: I haven't, but it's noted so that maybe I can get there some time in the future :)

Comment: One last shot since the chat cops showed up:  tonite it's Lesh himself and they're auctioning off Chicago tix!  ;-)  Cheers!